# Kendo UI Grid Json Data not loading

Tags: java, javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, amazon-dynamodb

I have problem in loading json data in kendo ui grid. I am able to load data in data grid as per response1 because db-table has multiple records the values are perfectly loaded in grid.If db contains only one record its not getting loaded.In kendo ui i have mentioned schema model for multiple records. I have load dynamically as per response.

Note in my webservice : Response2 does is just json object

Response 1 contains array of object.

How to load without mentioning schema in kendo ui grid?

How to implement dynamic schema in kendo ui grid?

My responses samples are:

Response1:

```
{"dataFile":[{"dataFileKey":"LLf38e8826-e86c-4b8e-ba76-5e9a036e9481","dataFileName":"10.10-si.dynamicrange-1k.2.EDS","experimentID":"47","id":"62"},{"dataFileKey":"LLf6ec3702-3714-4723-afdd-dd43cc97ed9e","dataFileName":"10.10-si.dynamicrange-1k.2.EDS","experimentID":"47","id":"56"},{"dataFileKey":"LL78df7a13-8de3-43e8-8976-9fd7513267d3","dataFileName":"10.10-si.dynamicrange-1k.2.EDS","experimentID":"47","id":"65"},{"dataFileKey":"LLb1efa732-1110-412d-b3b6-1b774397f5fe","dataFileName":"10.10-si.dynamicrange-1k.2.EDS","experimentID":"47","id":"55"},{"dataFileKey":"LLc87dfb0b-8f3c-4214-9e93-c879ec291fcf","dataFileName":"sample_results.xls","experimentID":"47","id":"52"},{"dataFileKey":"LLe78010d1-a6d4-4666-83d3-e10883cad64e","dataFileName":"ANdroid.rtf","experimentID":"47","id":"80"},{"dataFileKey":"LLdd323ac7-f11a-4211-acc7-b6f24e4c9b97","dataFileName":"10.10-si.dynamicrange-1k.2.EDS","experimentID":"47","id":"66"},{"dataFileKey":"LL322664c0-6834-4410-b09e-66b215a5a39c","dataFileName":"10.10-si.dynamicrange-1k.2.EDS","experimentID":"47","id":"63"},{"dataFileKey":"LL18eea7cd-fcf7-4e72-ab83-fd0eaaaf28dc","dataFileName":"10.10-si.dynamicrange-1k.2.EDS","experimentID":"47","id":"59"},{"dataFileKey":"LL8813caea-2bd8-406c-813d-820ad89a36b2","dataFileName":"UI .txt","experimentID":"47","id":"71"},{"dataFileKey":"LL0a58e6b5-44c5-44be-808c-a36edfc52157","dataFileName":"dynamodb-dg.pdf","experimentID":"47","id":"61"},{"dataFileKey":"LL84bf6b13-43f6-4b98-af33-3610fc04f30d","dataFileName":"10.10-si.dynamicrange-1k.2.EDS","experimentID":"47","id":"51"},{"dataFileKey":"LLa25825ce-0a87-403b-94fb-f6165eb9e8d5","dataFileName":"10.10-si.dynamicrange-1k.2.EDS","experimentID":"47","id":"64"},{"dataFileKey":"LL6647ad1e-8d8c-4891-b64a-9eced150b377","dataFileName":"sample_results.xls","experimentID":"47","id":"68"},{"dataFileKey":"LLf14ba2c7-7898-4392-92d6-b47ca08f9d63","dataFileName":"10.10-si.dynamicrange-1k.2.EDS","experimentID":"47","id":"67"},{"dataFileKey":"LL1a99399e-c266-4c5b-ba39-b1fdc5e073c5","dataFileName":"10.10-si.dynamicrange-1k.2.EDS","experimentID":"47","id":"57"},{"dataFileKey":"LLb2a68fcd-2e74-4257-8c8b-93e3463e7681","dataFileName":"dynamodb-dg.pdf","experimentID":"47","id":"60"}]}
```

Response 2:

```
{"dataFile":{"dataFileKey":"LL25586c00-d95f-41c8-ad49-370dfd29b68a","dataFileName":"ANdroid.rtf","experimentID":"30","id":"78"}}
```

I tried so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource : {
            type     : "json",
            transport: {
                read: "/lexaserver/rest/datafiles/all"
            },
            schema   : {
                data: "dataFile"
            },
            pageSize : 10
        },
        height     : 200,
        sortable   : true,
        reorderable: true,
        resizable  : true,
        pageable   : true,
        columns    : [
            {
                field: "id",
                title: "Data File ID",
                width: 110
            },
            {
                field: "dataFileName",
                title: "File Name",
                width: 110

            },
            {
                //  field: "dataFileKey",
                title   : "File Key",
                width   : 110,
                template: "<a class='download-files' fname=${dataFileName} key='${dataFileKey}' href=''>download file</a>",
            }
            //  { command: { text: "Download", click: showDetails }, title: " ", width: 30 }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your service is returning the data in different formats depending if you have one or many records. Kendo UI expects that it always have the same.

Options:

1. Modify your service for always returning the same format.
2. Implement a function that upon reception of the data checks for format and convert it into a common one.

Example of approach 2, change `schema` definition in `DataSource` to:

```
schema   : {
    parse: function (d) {
        if (d.dataFile) {
            return d.dataFile;
        } else {
            return [ d ];
        }
    }
},
```

Where I check if I received data has `d.dataFile` and returns it, otherwise returns an array with the content of the data received.

Comment: i have been searching in net for two days.thanx a lot

Comment: In this response datafiles having an object has an array if i load in grid it shows just objectObject. How to mention schema for this structure. {
    "experiment": [
        {
            "datafiles": "datafile [id=68, dataFileName=sample_results.xls, dataFileKey=LL6647ad1e-8d8c-4891-b64a-9eced150b377]",
            "description": "r",
            "design": "r",
            "id": "47",
            "name": "rrrr",
            "samples": "sample [id=59, sampleName=null]",
            "testVariables": "testvariable [id=59, testVariableName=testvariable]"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: In this structure `experiment` seems to be an `array`, might it contain more than one entry? does it always exist? You should think that this are JavaScript objects so you access them using regular JavaScript. The only question is that if the structure is _flexible_ you will have to check if `experiments` exist or not, if it is an array or a plain object, if it is a ... and then always send to KendoUI grid the same structure.

Comment: I have edited my response. I tried as per your first option but for single record grid is not getting loaded.

Comment: In your edited question you have changed the format of the data BUT it is still not the same when there is one element or when you have many. The former defines `dataFile` as an object while the later defines it as an `array`. This new question requires that your `parse` function instead of checking if `d.dataFile` exists, checks if it is an array or a plain object. BUT you are not still in "option 1", i.e. the server still returns different data format.